# HttpSessionListenerTest, getting an strange error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

Update. I used other which is to have a private static int total. I increment the total upon sessionCreated() and decrement sessionCounter upon sessionDestroyed(). The goal is to have the servlet to print out how many active users are on the web-app. The code is not working and I am getting a 0 value on total.

Another issue that I have, which is secondary and not so important is that my request variable is not working either. It is responsible for incrementing every time the servlet is called, and print out how many times you have visited the page.

Here is my HttpSessionListenerTest class:

```
public class HttpSessionListenerTest implements HttpSessionListener {

private static int total = 0;


public HttpSessionListenerTest() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public static int getTotal(){
    return total;
  }


/**
 * @see HttpSessionListener#sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent)
 */
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent e)  { 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             total++;




}

/**
 * @see HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent)
 */
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e)  { 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        total--; 



}
```

Here is my main servlet:

```
 public class ServletProjekt extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    int requests = 0; 
    requests++;
    request.getServletContext().log("Added a new request-log//abdi.");

    String firstName = request.getParameter("förnamn");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("efternamn");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String howoften = request.getParameter("howoften");
    String newsabout = request.getParameter("news");
    String[] age = request.getParameterValues("age");


    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("förnamn", firstName);
    session.setAttribute("efternamn", lastName);
    session.setAttribute("address", address);
    session.setAttribute("email", email);
    session.setAttribute("howoften", howoften);
    session.setAttribute("news", newsabout);
    session.setAttribute("age", age);




        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.write("<html>");
        printWriter.write("<h1> THANK YOU FOR YOUR INFORMATION</h1>");
        printWriter.write("<body>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your name:</p>" + firstName);
        printWriter.write("<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your last name:</p>" +lastName + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your address:</p>" +address + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your choice of often:</p>" +howoften + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your choice of news:</p>" +newsabout + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your email:</p>" +email + "<br>");




        **printWriter.write("<p>You have visited this page this many times:</p>" +requests + "<br>");**         
        printWriter.write("");

        for (String ages : age) {
            printWriter.write("<p>Hours:</p>" +ages + "<br>");
        }



        **printWriter.write("Active users:" + HttpSessionListenerTest.getTotal() + "<br>");**

        printWriter.write("<a href =\"GetAllCookies\">View All Cookies</a>");  


        printWriter.write("</body>");
        printWriter.write("</html>");
        printWriter.close();

}
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't help. **Where** (which line and which class exactly) are you getting the `NullPointerException`? Also, I recommend to put a **full stacktrace** should you need help when experiencing errors in your application.

Comment: As you can see from your exception the `NullPointerException` occurs in the following class `Abdi.ServletProjekt`, line 90 and **not** in your filter class `HttpSessionListenerTest`. Provide the code for the **correct** class, `Abdi.ServletProjekt`, and specify what line 90 is.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Yes, I can see that. And that is my main servlet which i specified in my question. Line 90 is what I also specified in my question. It is "int users =(Integer) ctx.getAttribute("totalusers");".

Comment: is it setting the attribute right ?

Comment: @Amrola Yes I think so.

Comment: please debug your code and make sure its setting the attribute and update us with the result

Comment: What browser mode are you using igcognition? If you are in that mode, there will be no session tracking available to you, you are in stealth mode

Comment: Please see my updated post, there is issues with your code in general (regarding counting users on `HttpSerssionFilter`.

Comment: Did you register your `HttpSessionListenerTest`?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi How do I register my HttpSessionListenerTest? I restarted eclipse and my server, and now it is displaying "1". I did it again and it switched to "0". Something is horribly wrong with my code and I don't know why. :/

Comment: Restarting your server deregisters your session all the time. Open all your browsers and hit the same servlet. If the numbers don't increase, then something is wrong. Register your `HttpSessionListener` by annotating it with `WebListener` (see example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)).

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Yes! It finally worked! Tried it on three different browsres and I got the value 3! Thank you so mich Buhkake Sindi!

Comment: @Abdi Tem I suggest trying all the solutions provided here and see which one you will go for. Plus, it is always good to accept and answer that has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

please check this tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/) .

in the tutorial he is trying to count the number of the users , to do so he used a static variable so that it could be shared across all users , like the following :

```
private static int totalActiveSessions;
```

Hope that Helps .

Answer (score 0):

[ServletContext.getAttribute(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) can return a `null` if there if there is no such attribute of specified `name`. Since you're trying to autobox an `Integer` to a primitive `int`, there is no way of the JVM to convert a `null` to a primitive type, so you're getting a `NullPointerException.

A simple fix:

```
ServletContext ctx=getServletContext();  
Integer users =(Integer) ctx.getAttribute("totalusers");
if (users == null) {
   users = 0;
}
```

Also, there is a problem with your `HttpSessionListenerTest`. There is **no** reference of active session counts. The filter gets called on every event and since `total` is not static, I'm afraid it will always be `0` (needs confirmation). Thus, you might get a value that you have only 1 user in session and your counter depends only on `total`. Here is a good fix:

```
@WebListener
public class HttpSessionListenerTest implements HttpSessionListener {


    /**
     * @see HttpSessionListener#sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent)
     */
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent e)  { 
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SessionContext ctx = e.getSession().getServletContext();
        Integer totalUsers = cxt.getAttribute("totalusers");
        if (totalUsers == null) {
            totalUsers = 0;
        } else {
            totalUsers += 1;
        }

        ctx.setAttribute("totalusers", totalUsers);  
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent)
     */
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent e)  { 
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SessionContext ctx = e.getSession().getServletContext();
        Integer totalUsers = cxt.getAttribute("totalusers");
        if (totalUsers == null) {
            totalUsers = 0;
        } else {
            totalUsers -= 1;
        }

        ctx.setAttribute("totalusers", totalUsers); 
    }
}
```

One other way is to have a `private static int sessionCounter`. Increment the `sessionCounter` upon `sessionCreated()` and decrement `sessionCounter` upon `sessionDestroyed()`.

Comment: SessionContext cannot be resolved to a type. What can I do about that?

Comment: You create `totalUers`, increment it, but use set `total` as the value -->no sense

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Thanks for your help. I tried having a private static int sessionCounter. Increment the session upon sessionCreated() and decrement sessionCounter upon sessionDestroyed()`. Good news: no error. Bad news: I'm getting a zero-value. Why? I am incrementing it. Why am I not getting a 1?

Comment: @Biu, Tanks! I fixed it.

Comment: @Abdi Tem if you use `sessionCounter`, you will have to access it statically, i.e., by calling `HttpSessionListenerTest.sessionCounter` in your servlet.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I did that, exactly. Still getting a 0 value.

Comment: Post your updated code. Also, how did you use my updated solution?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I updated my question. I used the last solution which was to to use a private static int total variable together with sessioncreated () (increment it) and sessiondestroyed () (decrement it)